# How can I install NPM package smaller than any specific version

Tags: npm

For example I want to install jQuery package using NPM, and the version of jQuery is smaller than 3.0.0.

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean "smaller"? "Smaller" in size or an earlier version?

Comment: `npm i jquery@2`?

Comment: It means below version.

Comment: thanx alexmac, but it is installing jquery 2.2.4 version.

Comment: I have answered to your question, @MohammedAshrafali. Look below...

Comment: `npm i -S jquery@2.2.4` then.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can install an npm package below a specific version using this:

```
npm install jquery@">=0.1.0 <3.0.0" // Using a range

npm install jquery@"<3.0.0" // Below a specific version
```

You can refer to this link for more information: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 2):

If by "smaller" you are referring to an earlier version, you can add this line to your dependencies in your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "2.2.4"
}
```

and then run the `npm install` command. Feel free to replace the version `2.2.4` with whichever version you are trying to install.

Comment: Thankyou Dimitris

Comment: @MohammedAshrafali please mark this as the right answer, if it was.

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all,
for having a better picture of the jquery,
you can get the available `jquery versions`, on your terminal, likes so: `npm view jquery versions`

This command will give you the whole history of available versions, so far:
[image]

So, some other ways to install `jquery` on smaller versions to ver. `3.0.0` are:

- As previously mentioned: `npm i jquery@"<3.0.0"` or `npm i jquery@">1.6.2 <3.0.0"`
- By using the `^` symbol, like: `npm i jquery@^2.0.0` **or** `npm i jquery@2.0.x` **or** `npm i jquery@^2` **or** `npm i jquery@^2.*`.

The `^` symbol covers all the range, from the mentioned `minor`, until the previous version of the next `major` version.(`^MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`).

e.g. jquery@^2.1.3, will install from version `>= 2.1.3 < 3.0.0`

You can play, with the **npm semver calculator** here : https://semver.npmjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think you must update the dependency version in "package.json" (which you required) and then run the "npm install" command.It will update the package with which we added in the "package.json" file.
Hope this will fix the issue.