# How can I change "x-data-grid" to a lower version?

Tags: reactjs, mern

I want to change x-data-grid in package.json to see if my error is because of the version

google it and right by hand in the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install npm package smaller than any specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587638/how-can-i-install-npm-package-smaller-than-any-specific-version)

Comment: uninstall the package and install specific version of it by calling `npm install x-data-grid@1.2.3` (change numbers before using this command).