# How to solve JHipster automatically installing a beta instead of stable version?

Tags: npm, jhipster

I ran the command `npm install -g generator-jhipster` as JHipster's website states on the Homepage at chapter "JHipster Quick Start".

NPM installed version `v8.0.0-beta.1`. How to get rid of a beta and install the latest *stable* version?

Comment: That's the version the maintainers have tagged as "latest": https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster?activeTab=versions. If you want a different version, be more specific.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install npm package smaller than any specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587638/how-can-i-install-npm-package-smaller-than-any-specific-version)

Comment: Solves partly full question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user **jonsharpe** I could install the "stable" version. The developers would not care and ship a bleeding edge version, though this seems uncommon to me. But it is simple to remove it. If one installs a global version, it it required to remove it using the flag `-g`. [Source: How to Remove a Global Package with npm Uninstall](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/npm-uninstall-how-to-remove-a-package/)

These steps solved my question:

1. `npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster`
2. Select a version tag at [npm - generator-jhipster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster?activeTab=versions)
3. `npm install -g generator-jhipster@7.9.3`

That's it folks.